# Unity. Как останавливать NavMeshAgent?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли настроить NavMeshAgent таким образом, что бы юниты не толкали друг друга ?

Например есть 10 юнитов, скажем всем юнитам идти в нулевую точку

```
agent.SetDestination(Vector3.zero);
```

вот дошел первый до нулевой, и потом подошли остальные, и они будут сдвигать друг друга дабы тоже попасть в точку назначения.

К сожалению путь прокладывается без учета радиуса NavMeshAgent (

Есть ли возможность предотвратить подобное, или надо писать свой алгоритм поиска пути ?

Comment: Можете попробовать Nav Mesh Obstacle. Этот компанент симулирует препятствия
[ссылка](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NavMeshObstacle.html)

Comment: К сожалению тогда при расчете пути по NavMesh будут проблемы, так как NavMeshObstacle перекрывает NavMesh и расчитывать позицию придется с какой то другой точки, ну и это может создать нагрузку при большом кол-ве юнитов.